# Android MediaStore from Air App

Tags: android, air, air-android

I am writing an Air app that needs to access the Android Media Store.

So far tried:
Direct access to the SQLite database. Seems Android does not give permissions for this.
Next attempted calling a native Android app from my Air app. Burrito does not seem to support NativeProcess for Android.

Any ideas or workarounds?
Or do we drop AS3 and code native for Android?

Thanks, Ronnie

Answer (score 2):

The only solution today is to combine a native apk with an AIR for Android apk.  More details here:
http://elromdesign.com/blog/2010/10/29/hacking-native-android-with-air-app-to-allow-air-access-unavailable-apis/